# design cassandra data model for rest api analysis

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

Basically, the analysis data for record usage of restful api like below

```
public class UsageData {
    public String url;
    public double duration;
    //others        
}
```

for example, the url may be like

```
http://host:port/api/v1/users/{id}/classes
```

if i want to put this data into cassandra, how should I design the table. Because there are dynamic values in the url, how to design the key?

for example
if I would like to query how many times of the http://host:port/api/v1/users/{id}/classes have been called?

And the url also may include query parameter like

```
http://host:port/api/v1/users/{id}/classes?name=xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to count only {id} usages or also want to analize parameters?
If you only want to count usages by {id} read this link, it is probably exactly what you want to do.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

Answer (score 1):

If parameters do not play any role you can split url to resource part (`http://host:port/api/v1/users/`), id part (`{id}`) and subresource part (`classes`).

**Option 1:** Make your `resource` `partition key` and in that row you can cluster data by `{id}` part and `subresource` part. That way you will get in one row all information about one resource. This will answer following queries efficiently:

- give me all duration for some `resource` for all `{id}` values
- give me duration for combination of `resource`, `{id}` and `subresource` part

**Option 2:** Other way around you can make `{id}` `partition key` and have `resource` part and `subresource` part as clustering keys. This way in one row you will have all durations for some `{id}` for all resources and all `subresources`.

This will answer following queries efficiently:

- give me all duration for some `{id}` for all `resource` and `subresource` values
- give me duration for combination of `{id}`, `resource` and `subresource` part

**Decision** can be made on use case, what is thing you need more, to get durations for `resource` or for `{id}`